# Получить ip адрес из getaddrinfo()

Tags: linux, g++

Подскажите, как получить ipv4 адрес из `getaddrinfo()` под линусом.

Под Windows используется вот такая конструкция: `unsigned int ip = ((struct sockaddr_in*)ai->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;` . Под линуксом в ней 0.

Comment: Может, приведите минимальный кусок кода, воспроизводящий проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Брал значение из первого элемента, а там ipv6 и естественно 0.

Код для получения ipv4 адреса:

```
    char *ip = "yandex.ru";
    struct addrinfo *ai = 0, *pai;
    unsigned int ipr = 0;

    if(getaddrinfo(ip, 0, 0, &ai))
        return 0;

    pai = ai;
    while(pai){
        printf("FOUND %d\r\n", pai->ai_family, " ");
        if(pai->ai_family == PF_INET){
        printf("ip: %d\r\n", ((struct sockaddr_in*)pai->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr);
      break;
}
        pai = pai->ai_next;
    }

    if(pai)
        ipr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)pai->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
    else
        ipr = 0;

    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    printf("Result: %d.\r\n", ipr);
```